# Memory leak issue with Analyzer?

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks

i am beginner in my project got crashed in some of view. i checked with help of Analyze which is in sub item of RUN in xcode. here i got some of issue list that is leak object here i added two kind of images it represents the leak object i can't able to understand what is the problem happened please any one help me

[image: issue in appdelegate class] [image: issue in XMLparse class]

Comment: Turn ARC on, or `-release` some variables properly.

Comment: can you which object i didn't release from above two images please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is obvious that you `create` or `retain` some object, but forget to release it.

From your two images, you alloc for `appDelegate.Notify_array` without release, if the `Notify_array` is `strong-property`, you can `autorelease` it when `alloc`.

And you also retain the `receivedData` without release.

Maybe you release all the objects in `dealloc`, but the naming-style is not good, it is good to have one underline prefix for instance variable.

Memory leaks will not result in crash, but access wild pointers will.
For the crash of your project, I advise you to open `NSZombie Detect` to catch it.

Comment: `recievedData` does not leak because it is an iVar.  A `-release` would complicate setting it later on.

Comment: @CodaFi Yes, I know. So I suggest a iVar naming style.

Answer (score 1):

XCode analyzer is just used to find any potential leaks, it doesn't tell exactly why any crash happening. In screenshot , it is saying theConnection is not released anywhere for the alloc statement.In screenshot 2, it is saying appDelegate.Notify_array is not released anywhere for the alloc statement. The execution path is shown in blue arrows.

Add the corresponding release statements. This analyzer leak will go off.

Add an exception breakpoint and also enable zombie object in xcode, it can help to find most crashes. Also see any error message logged in xcode console.